# How to avoid this valgrind warning on realloc?

Tags: c, valgrind

I have been wrangling with a what seems to be a strange case of `realloc` not working well with valgrind. It seems as if I am either allocating too much somehow or am using `realloc` incorrectly. I take valgrind errors seriously and such an error worries me deeply.

Minimal working example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test {
    size_t n;
    size_t r;
    int **ptrs;
} test;

test *new_test() {
    test *t = malloc(sizeof(test));
    t->n = 0; //number of elements
    t->r = 1; //reserve
    t->ptrs = calloc(t->r, sizeof(*(t->ptrs))); //calloc inits so we don't have to
    return t;
}

void push_back_test(test *t, int *ptr) {
    if (t->n == t->r) {
        t->r <<= 1;
        int **temp_ptr = realloc(t->ptrs, sizeof(t->ptrs) * t->r);
        if (temp_ptr) {
            t->ptrs = temp_ptr;
        } else {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //NULL out the rest 
        for (int **ptri = t->ptrs + t->n; ptri < t->ptrs + t->r; ++ptri) {
            (*ptri) = NULL;
        }
    }
    t->ptrs[t->n] = ptr;
    ++(t->n);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    test *t = new_test();
    int *a = calloc(2, sizeof(int)); //calloc inits
    int *b = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    int *c = calloc(8, sizeof(int));

    push_back_test(t, a);
    push_back_test(t, b);
    push_back_test(t, c);
    push_back_test(t, a);
    push_back_test(t, b);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==26528== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26528== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26528== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26528== Command: ./test
==26528== 
==26528== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26528==    at 0x435A32: __linkin_atfork (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x414905: ptmalloc_init.part.8 (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x414C7F: malloc_hook_ini (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x465B1A: _dl_get_origin (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x436AB4: _dl_non_dynamic_init (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x437916: __libc_init_first (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x40140F: (below main) (in /----/----/test)
==26528== 
==26528== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26528==    at 0x4104BA: _int_free (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x412C3B: _int_realloc (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x414046: realloc (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x40109D: push_back_test (test.c:20)
==26528==    by 0x4011FB: main (test.c:44)
==26528== 
==26528== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26528==    at 0x410518: _int_free (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x412C3B: _int_realloc (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x414046: realloc (in /----/----/test)
==26528==    by 0x40109D: push_back_test (test.c:20)
==26528==    by 0x4011FB: main (test.c:44)
==26528== 
==26528== 
==26528== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26528==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26528==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==26528== 
==26528== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==26528== 
==26528== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26528== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==26528== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Now I know the first error is probably a problem with my libc, but the rest is essentially telling me that I am not nulling out all the memory I have allocated and am passing around garbage, which I believe cannot be as I am nulling out what has been newly allocated.

I have tried many variations on this, and they either (rightly) crash or give these messages. I am at a loss.

EDIT: original code that I have a problem in was more correct than this.
and I have now fixed the MWE, still the same.

Comment: test *new_test() does not return a pointer to a type `test *`.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: I have in original code. MWE was wrong, and is now right with same results.

Comment: Find that slightly difficult to believe - these errors would be a direct result of not having the return statement.

Comment: `gcc -std=gnu11 -Wall -static -g test.c -o test`
then
`valgrind ./test`
valgrind output was same as original

Comment: I get no errors reported with the updated code.

Comment: I get no warnings from valgrind. I notice your valgrind line numbers do not line up with the code.

Comment: Might it be a problem with my libc?

Comment: I can reproduce this, but only when compiling with `-static`. I'm almost positive that all of these are the result of malloc hooks.

Comment: Updated valgrind output! ... Ah! static! that must be it! Thank you so much! Yes that would make sense!

Comment: `int **temp_ptr = realloc(t->ptrs, sizeof(t->ptrs) * t->r);` --> `int **temp_ptr = realloc(t->ptrs, sizeof *t->ptrs * t->r);`

Comment: That also doesn't fix it, but it is a bug.

Comment: @dho It does, see [This](http://pastebin.com/zDEZw9a3). Just don't forget to free that memory allocated.

Comment: @dho Why did I get no warnings like OP does?

Comment: You did not compile with `-static`. Or if you did, your libc's malloc implementation isn't as confusing to Valgrind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that glibc is not Valgrind-clean. Normally, these errors would appear to come from your `libc.so.6`, which Valgrind has built-in suppressions for. When you link statically, these issues appear to originate from your binary, and so are not suppressed.

You can solve this by either not linking statically or by using [suppressions](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) and [suppression files](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.suppfiles)

If you look at what is being complained about, it is that some thread-local storage is being compared to NULL. If you attach a debugger, it turns out things are initialized just fine, and the issue is a false positive.

More information can be found at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506134/valgrind-errors-when-linked-with-static-why).

Of course, multiple comments point out your original bug with `new_test` and an existing bug with the size you pass to `realloc`. Once those are fixed, the Valgrind warnings remain, and this is why.

Comment: Thanks, yes static is the issue. The bug with `new_test` was not present in the original code, which is why I started this question in the first place, however the size bug, though ultimately not a consequential one as `sizeof(void **)==sizeof(void *)` on my platform (and I am assuming most mainstream ones as well,) is one that could have maybe caused problems, though again, changed nothing for valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to call `realloc` with an incorrect size:

```
realloc(t->ptrs, sizeof(t->ptrs) * t->r);
```

Should be instead:

```
realloc(t->ptrs, sizeof(*t->ptrs) * t->r);
```

Since `t->ptrs` is defined as `int **ptrs;`, the computation gives the same result on your and most modern platforms. Therefore this error has no consequences and does not explain the problem, as dho correctly commented.

Comment: This is true, but fixing this does not fix the problem in Valgrind.

Comment: This is not what was causing the issue, but is also a valid point, thank you.