# Valgrind don't show line and files of error

Tags: c, linux, arm, valgrind

I have program that compile with -g and -o0 , and I run this program with valgrind 
 :

```
valgrind --leak-check=full \
         --show-leak-kinds=all \
         --track-origins=yes \
         --verbose \
         --log-file=valgrind-out.txt \
         ./executable exampleParam1
```

I have some error but valgrind doesn't present the file and line

```
==22544== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22544==    at 0x8048654: memcpy (in /path_to_binary)
==22544==  Uninitialised value was created 
==22544==    at 0x80486DB: brk  (in /path_to_binary)
```

How to make `valgrind` present to line and file of errors?

Comment: Can we see the build output (in verbose mode, so we can see the actual flags used)? Can we see your exact build settings (`Makefile`, `CMakeLists.txt` or similar)? And you don't `strip` the executable once built?

Comment: Also note that those functions mentioned by Valgrind are system functions that one generally don't have the source to. Doesn't Valgrind say anything else? Please include the full output of Valgrind.

Comment: GCC command line options are case sensitive; `-o` and `-O` do completely different things.  Try again with `-O0`.  Also make sure there isn't another `-O` option later on the command line; the last one wins.

Comment: `arm-linux-gcc -static -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP...` I don't strip that binary ...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7506134/72178

Comment: Does your executable have a `main()` and maybe other functions that you are expecting to see in the callstack?