# Is there any sanitizer setting in GCC or Clang that can detect the use of uninitialized heap-allocated memory?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, address-sanitizer

These C and C++ programs use uninitialized memory:

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    double* p = malloc(100*sizeof(double));

    printf("%f\n", p[22]);

    free(p);
}
```

C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double* p = new double[100];

    std::cout << p[22] << '\n';

    delete [] p;
}
```

I tried different `-fsanitize` options with GCC and Clang, but none reported an error:

C:

```
$ gcc -fsanitize=address,undefined uninit.c && ./a.out 
-0.000002
$ clang -fsanitize=address,undefined uninit.c && ./a.out 
-0.000002
$ clang -fsanitize=memory uninit.c && ./a.out 
0.000000
```

C++:

```
$ g++ -fsanitize=address,undefined uninit.cpp && ./a.out 
-1.83255e-06
$ clang++ -fsanitize=address,undefined uninit.cpp && ./a.out 
-1.83255e-06
$ clang++ -fsanitize=memory uninit.cpp && ./a.out 
0
```

This is especially surprising for Clang, because its documentation [shows](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html#usage) a similar example that does work as advertised, on my system (Thanks, *ssbssa*)

My compiler versions are GCC 12.2.0 and Clang 15.0.7.

Is there any sanitizer setting in GCC or Clang that can detect the use of uninitialized heap-allocated memory in these examples?

---

*Edit:* As *ssbssa* pointed out in the comments, this appears to have been fixed in Clang 16.

Comment: Something like this is beyond the capabilities of the compiler. You're looking for a static analysis tool, like `valgrind`. `valgrind` will nail this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `valgrind` does catch this, but it also floods the screen with messages (on my Linux system) even when there is no bug.

Comment: Well, those messages must indicate other problems with the code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Even for trivial code, I can get flooded with complaints. For example, if I add `for(int i=0;i<100;++i) p[i]=0;` to the above, `valgrind` still complaints if I use static linking.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I get 0 warnings. https://pastebin.com/raw/3CsbWjmi

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's not static. What if you add `-static`?

Comment: `-static` won't even compile. `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory` -- why would I want to do a daft thing like that, linking to libstdc++ statically?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Your users might be missing the right library version. I also get flooded with "warnings" from valgrind if I link dynamically, but to newer library versions than what `valgrind` was designed to work with.

Comment: Memory Sanitizer should catch this, the example in the docu is [very similary](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html#usage) to this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: valgrind is great, but it's not [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) - just the opposite.  It actually executes the program in a virtual environment where extra checks are done.

Comment: @ssbssa I guess it's a newer version than the one I have? 18 vs 15? I installed mine from stable sources a few months ago. I'm glad that clang is making progress here. Consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: The example is in the wiki since the [first revision](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer/efc00bd64800aefd53b96d563004ccc7de2c431d), so no, I don't think a newer version changes this. I think this is one of the main features of Memory Sanitizer, and should work with each version since it was introduced.

Comment: @ssbssa The example from the Wiki works, as advertised (reporting an error), on my system, but my example does not (prints `0` with no error messages). A bug in clang perhaps?

Comment: Then I would try to find out which difference makes this work. double -> int, or the if() maybe? And then a bug report.

Comment: @ssbssa I don't know if this has been fixed in the current version

Comment: According to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/65zorGdcb), it works since clang 16.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any sanitizer setting in GCC or Clang that can detect the use of uninitialized heap-allocated memory?

Definitely: `clang -fsanitize=memory` does that.

The issue in your examples is that uninitialized memory is passed to system functions (which aren't instrumented) and doesn't get detected.

A more realistic example which actually *uses* uninitialized memory instead of just printing it does produce the expected errors.

As other comments show, you can catch this error using Valgrind (which doesn't require instrumenting the code).

> valgrind still complaints if I use static linking.

Don't do static linking then? [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7515951/50617) of why static linking is "bad" for Valgrind.

Comment: Did you see @ssbssa 's last comment? *"uninitialized memory is passed to system functions"* - I'm passing a `double`, not its address, to `printf`.